# How to use selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2 while creating script with RC

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

```
package com.html;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class Html5 extends TestCase{`enter code here`
    Selenium selenium1;
    public void setUp()
    {
        selenium1=new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://live.com");
        selenium1.start();
    }
}
```

Error appearing in com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium; and DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://live.com"); line.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

First :

What the `enter code here` string does there ?

Secondly :

If there is an error in the `import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;` and in the `new DefaultSelenium`, it's certainly that the jars are not in your classpath

`selenium-server-standalone` contains the Selenium server classes, but not the client ones, where `DefaultSelenium is`. You'll have to bring the client jars in your classpath, that is `selenium2-java` for this version I think

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give Path to firefox.exe in your Constructor..So

```
selenium1 = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://live.com");   Goes like
selenium1 = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox C:\Documents and Settings\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe","http://live.com");
```

Try this once.